# Is there a way for a smart contract to manage a codebase?

Tags: contract-design, contract-deployment

For example, could one set up a smart contract with governance protocols which could merge PR’s in a github repository? How might one govern open source via a smart contract?

In a related vein, is there a method to automatically deploy to ethereum from a github repository?

Comment: Smart contracts are turing complete, so it's possible. Technically, you could implement a Solidity compiler in solidity. You can use an oracle to read the source code from github.com, compile it and deploy it from a smart contract.

Comment: In your second question what do you mean by "deploy to ethereum from a github repository"? What is being a deployed? It's fairly straightforward to deploy a contract from its repository to the network. But it would be unusual to deploy an arbitrary codebase to the network, since it's not very efficient at data storage.